# Alternative low-moment measure of skewness

Tags: statistics, reference-request, volatility-skew, skewness, moments

$$
\widehat{\text {Skew}}_{i, t}=\frac{3 \cdot\left[\hat{\mu}_{i, t}-\operatorname{median}\left(r_{i, d, t}\right)\right]}{\hat{\sigma}_{i, t}}
$$

is called Low Moment Skewness by Baltas and Salinas (2019) who don't give a citation for this alternative measure of skewness. What is its source, or where else is it used?

Others call it the Pearson 2 skewness coefficent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pearson 2 skewness, which compares mean and median, lying between $-3$ and $3$ while being zero for symmetric distributions, was introduced by

> Yule, G. U. and Kendall, M. G. (1950), An Introduction to the Theory of Statistics, 3rd edition, Harper Publishing Company, 162-163.